# restsharp PUT request error --> "StatusCode: InternalServerError, Content-Type: application/json, Content-Length: -1)"

Tags: c#, request, restsharp, put

I want to do a PUT request via a REST API. I've got the access_token, which should be correct. I'm trying to upload a JSON object of relation, but I get the following error:

restsharp PUT request error:

> “StatusCode: InternalServerError, Content-Type: application/json,
>   Content-Length: -1)”

```
public void Store(HiveClient hiveClient,string _putUrl, string _url, string _clientId, string _clientSecret, HiveObject objToStore)
{
    hiveClient = new HiveClient(_url, _clientId, _clientSecret);
    hiveClient.CheckIfFileExists();
    string token = hiveClient.restToken;
    HiveObject hiveObject = objToStore;
    var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(hiveObject);
    RestClient restClient = new RestClient(_putUrl);
    RestRequest request = new RestRequest(Method.PUT);
    request.AddHeader("Authorization", token);
    request.AddParameter("application/json; charset=utf-8", json, ParameterType.RequestBody);
    request.AddJsonBody(json);
    request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;
    IRestResponse respons = restClient.Execute<HiveObject>(request);
    var deserialize = new JsonDeserializer();
    var output = deserialize.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, string>>(respons);
}
```

Comment: The question is?

Comment: What kind if authorization is needed? Because i thought tokens always need basic or bearer as authorization header.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest reading the docs, really.

```
public void Store(string _putUrl, string _url, string _clientId, string _clientSecret, HiveObject objToStore)
{
    var hiveClient = new HiveClient(_url, _clientId, _clientSecret);
    hiveClient.CheckIfFileExists();
    string token = hiveClient.restToken;

    var restClient = new RestClient(_putUrl);
    var request = new RestRequest()
        .AddHeader("Authorization", token)
        .AddJsonBody(objToStore);

    var result = restClient.Put<Dictionary<string, string>>(request);
}
```